# Load multiple same angular selector tag in HTML

Tags: html, angular7

I have a concept that trying to create multiple app root component in index.html. When I loaded the page it rendered first app-root component but the second one doesn't render.

Below is sample code.

```
 <body>
  <app-root controlId='S1'></app-root>//component1
  <app-root controlId='S2'></app-root>//component2
  <script src="angularbundled.js"/>
 </body>
```

I'm expecting if i add two app-root into html it will render the two angular component in my page. Example if i injected ,  in html it should display two angular component. I didn't use angular dynamic load component because my current system are not suitable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple instances of the same root application in Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39231943/multiple-instances-of-the-same-root-application-in-angular-2)

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for..Btw thanks.